# Remove all buttons from panel

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

I am trying to remove all buttons from panel.  somehow it remove only half with my code.  i do not know why.  this is in c# windows form.  can someone explain please.  thank you.  code as follows:
Added using

```
        for(int ii=1; ii<=6; ii++)
        {
            for(int jj=1; jj<=5; jj++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.TabStop = false;
                b.Width = 146;
                b.Height = 91;
                b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
                panel.Controls.Add(b);
            }
        }
```

Remove using

```
        foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
        {
            c.Click -= new EventHandler(this.b_Click);
            panel.Controls.Remove(c);
            c.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Is this really how your code looks?  I'm surprised the compiler would allow you to modify a collection you're iterating over.  Oh, wait--maybe the compiler lets it go but it causes exception at runtime.  In any case, I'm surprised your code is compiling and running to completion.

Comment: Do you have any sub-panels? If so, you need to build a recursion method to get all child controls.

Comment: no subpanel. just one form with panel and lots of buttons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list of controls is iterating to the half because the iterator increase while the amount of items are decrease. In the middle of the (internal) index of your Control-List is bigger than the amount of items.

Save the list of items first:

```
List<Button> buttons = panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
foreach (Button btn in buttons)
{
    btn.Click -= new EventHandler(this.b_Click); //It's unnecessary
    panel.Controls.Remove(btn);
    btn.Dispose();
}
```

edit: Why do you remove the Click-Event, if you dispose the button? After Disposing, the events are cleared and the button could not be used either.´

If you want a 1 line solution, you could only use Dispose. It will remove the buttons automatically from the panel an clear all events etc.

```
panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(btn => btn.Dispose());
```

Comment: thank you for the explaination Mitja.  i was thinkg the foreach loop actually remembers the max item count.  now is all clear up for me.

Comment: What is `this.b_Click` ? If each button has his event ?

Comment: I copied the code of Jim above. Read my edit: It's unnecessary to remove events when the control will be explicity disposed later on.

Comment: panel has buttons and panels (that contains buttons and other panels) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question in detail. Please create a new question with reference to my answer. It looks like off topic in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList())
{
    panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
    c.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to modify a collection (`Controls`) while iterating it, so that code shouldn't work.

Try simply:

```
panel.Controls.Clear();
```

You'll be fine without the call to `Dispose`.

Edit: if you do only want to remove all `Button`'s (and have other and possibly nested controls), you can do something like this:

```
private void FindControls<T>( List<T> list, Control parent ) where T : Control
{
    foreach( Control c in parent.Controls )
    {
        if( c is T )
            list.Add( (T)c );
        FindControls( list, c );
    }
}

// and use like so:
var list = new List<Button>();
FindControls( list, this );
foreach( var b in list )
    b.Parent.Controls.Remove( b );
```

Comment: But what if the Panel also has controls that are not buttons and may be required to stay?

Comment: @RFerwerda Yeah in that case that would obvisouly not work very well. I just "fixed" the code he had.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  i do not have any other controls other than buttons, but i do not want to cause any problem without disposing them.  tried assigning to list and it works.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the compiler allows this sort of thing, but usually results in a run-time exception. You need to iterate over a collection that is not being modified.

```
    List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>(panel.Controls)
    foreach (Control c in ctrls)
    {
        if(c is Button)
        {
             c.Click -= new EventHandler(this.b_Click);
             panel.Controls.Remove(c);
            c.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not that this makes a material difference, but I'd probably just do `foreach (var c in ctrls.ToList())`.

Comment: panel has buttons and panels (that contains buttons and other panels) ?